# PHP: Get contents of shared dropbox link w/password?

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox, guzzle, goutte

I'm building a fairly large Laravel app, and part of the process involves downloading pictures from several remote sources. Sometimes that's direct URL, sometimes FTP...and sometimes via Dropbox. I have no control over how the info is sent in, but I'm expected to build a method to process it.

In one case, we have a zip file hosted on dropbox. We receive a share link w/password. We do have a Dropbox acct and app, but this zip is on a third parties account, not ours.

With some googling, I see that you can add ?raw=1 to the share link to automatically start the download, however it doesn't appear that their is a way to add the password to the URL, or to get this file via dropbox API (unless i'm missing something?). I've even tried using Goutte to submit the form and download the file but i'm running into trouble with security on their end...

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Goutte attempt...

```
  $client = new Client;

  $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx?raw=1');

  // select the form and fill in some values
  $form = $crawler->selectButton('Enter')->form();
  $form['password'] = 'xxxxxx';

  $crawler = $client->submit($form);

  var_dump($crawler);
```

"Dropbox - 405 Error (405)Something went wrong. Don't worry, your files are still safe and the Dropboxers have been notified. Check out our Help Center and forums for help, or head back to home."

Comment: Have a look at flysystem, it's a package that allows for easy use of a lot of filesystem services http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/

Comment: Dropbox doesn't currently offer a programmatic interface for downloading folder shared links with a password, but we'll consider this a feature request.

Comment: Thanks! I feel good knowing the blame doesn't rest on my shoulders :D

Comment: I think a good place to start would be on the Dropbox developers site https://www.dropbox.com/developers